# Angular 8 - Material Auto Complete - mat-form-field

Tags: angular

I have created a registration form and I looking for something like that example: 
[image: Example]

I couldn't find any relative info on angular documentation so I'm seeking here for an answer.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this , it's called chips in angular material : https://material.angular.io/components/chips/examples

Stackblitz demo : https://stackblitz.com/angular/mjmrekdgjak?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchips-input-example.ts